In mingw/msys2, use `pip install abc` or `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-python-abc`?
My question is related to this: Failing to install python cryptography library using pip on msys2/mingw
In that question, pip install cryptography failed but pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-cryptography installed successfully.
There is another question: msys: pip install cffi fails due to undefined references
In the comment, it's suggested to use pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-python-cffi instead of pip install cffi.
So my question is a more general one: is it recommoned (or even required) to install a pip package, let me call it abc, by pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-python-abc instead of  pip install abc?

One way to look at it: installing with pacman is for system packages only (the global Python environment), and installing with pip is for virtual environments only. I really think it would be bad to mix both installation methods. -- This is true not only for msys/mingw but for any system.

package abc is preinstalled with Python. And if abc means "any-name" then sometimes modules may have C/C++ code and using pacman you may get precompiled version, and using pip it may need to install C/C++ compiler, and some C/C++ libraries to compile it - and sometimes it can make big problem. So pacman can make it simpler - but it may not have the newest version.

@sinoroc Only some part of pip packages are provided by pacman. If it's recommended not to mix pacman and pip, there will be only one choice, ie, pip. then what's the point of providing pacman for some part of the packages?

Some things can be hard to install with pip, so it can be useful to have them as pacman-installable, in which case you would use them in combination with a virtual environment where the system site packages are available (importable). -- And also some Python packages installable with pacman might be there because they are dependencies of another pacman-installable package (that itself might or might not be installable with pip). -- There might be other reasons as well.
